# Custom Transit writer for Joda time in Clojure

Tags: clojure, transit

[Clojure's transit](https://github.com/cognitect/transit-clj) does not support the Joda time format out of the box. How can I add write support for `org.joda.time.DateTime`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add this function:

```
(def joda-time-writer
  (transit/write-handler
   (constantly "m")
   #(-> % coerce/to-date .getTime)
   #(-> % coerce/to-date .getTime .toString)))
```

And use it like this:

```
(transit/writer out :json
                    {:handlers {org.joda.time.DateTime joda-time-writer}})
```

Comment: This is explained in more detail here: http://increasinglyfunctional.com/2014/09/02/custom-transit-writers-clojure-joda-time/

Comment: Where does `out` come from?

Answer (score 0):

To get this to work with ring-middleware-format, do this, using the `joda-time-writer` function posted by David J.

```
(defn wrap-format [handler]
  (let [transit-opts {:handlers {org.joda.time.DateTime
                                 joda-time-writer}}]
    (wrap-restful-format handler
                         {:response-options
                          {:transit-json transit-opts
                           :transit-messagepack transit-opts}})))
```